# Blender 2.80 hair dynamics. As soon as I advance a few frames hair goes haywire

Tags: hair

When I turn on hair dynamics for my fur particles, they go haywire as soon as I advance a few frames. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm not very experienced in blender. I wasn't able to find any answers online, so if anyone has any insight it would be much appreciated. I am using cycles if that matters.

Frame 2 of the model

[image: Frame 2 of the model]

Frame 4 of the model

[image: Frame 4 of the model]

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply scale and transform
2. Set origin to geometry
3. Before tweaking any settings run hair simulation, then go back to frame 1 and assign vertex group and other values according to your character
4. Also try reducing segments in 'Emission'

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to what JTN said, you also appear to have stiffness set to 10. This could be causing some problems. Try lowering it to something like 2 and see if that helps.